# How to change the data in react, i copy to the props to state

Tags: reactjs

---

### How to change the data

I have read a book,  the author said do not copy to the props to state,  so if i want want to change the data, which is the right way.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/EPUFq.png]

Comment: It will be better if your post your code instead of the snapshot

Comment: duplicate question

Comment: this is the first time to use the stack,  i did not  know it...  i will post code next time, thank you@ Shubham Khatri

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well when you go through the docs it states that, `setting props to the initial state is an anti pattern`. So instead of initially setting your prop to state, you can do that in the `componentDidMount()` lifecycle function

```
constructor(props) {
   super(props);
   this.state = {
      birthdate: null,
      name: null,
      contact: null,
      gender: null,
      photoUrl: 'https://facebook.github.io/react/img/logo_og.png'
   }
}
componentDidMount() {
    const {birthdate, name, contact, gender, photoUrl} = this.props;
    this.setState({
        birthdate: birthdate,
        name: name,
        gender: gender,
        contact: contact,
        photoUrl: photoUrl
    })
}
```

Comment: thank you very much  so if i instead of initially setting prop to state, the code is right,  yes?

Comment: Worth noting that if you don't plan on mutating those values it's pointless adding the `props` to the `state`

Comment: The thing i want to do is change the values, thank you for your remind@ Glitch100

Comment: Apart from this your code is right. Happy to help :)